# JasmineNodeOpts - Printing Protractor Test Results

Tags: jasmine, protractor

**Background**: I'm using Jasmine as my test framework for Protractor, I've been using [jasmine spec reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) for reporting.  Yesterday I slightly changed my `jasmineNodeOpts` parameters in my protractor conf.js to include the `print()` function i.e.

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
    includeStackTrace : true,
    isVerbose : true,
    print: function () {}
},
```

I added this print function because I learned it would remove the `.` before each report.  For example, my test reports used to come back:

```
.    ✓ should display a profile question about IT loads
.    ✓ checks the width of the progress bar
.    ✓ selects an option from the radio buttons and updates the progress bar
```

And now those leading dots are removed.  However, now my final report has also slight changed from:

```
14 specs, 2 failures Finished in 45.473 seconds // this is the old, desired output
```

To this:

```
Executed 14 of 14 specs (2 FAILED) in 45 secs. // this is my current, undesired output
```

I want the best of both worlds, having the `.` removed from my report but retaining the previous overall report.

**Problem**: I cannot find *detailed* documentation on `jasmineNodeOpts` and/or that `print()` function.  It is mentioned in [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/docs/protractor-configuration.md) and the [protractor reference conf](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) but there is no real documentation on how it works, only very weak examples are provided.

Does anyone know where I can learn more about this `print()` function and/or how to change my final test output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one solution for this case. This is kind of a hack, a small change in the [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) - [displaySummary](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/blob/master/src/spec-display.js#L34) logic

Replace the method - `summary(metrics)` at `node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/src/spec-display.js` with the below logic

```
summary: function (metrics) {

    this.log(metrics.executedSpecs + ' specs, ' +  metrics.failedSpecs+ ' failures Finished in ' + metrics.duration);
    if (metrics.random) {
      this.log('Randomized with seed ' + metrics.seed + '.');
    }
  },
```

I just checked and its generating the execution summary as you are expecting

```
Spec started

   - sample test
    √ Dummy Test
    √ Dummy Test2
    √ Dummy Test3


3 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 27.544 seconds

  3 specs,0 failures Finished in 28 secs
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that.  Worked perfectly.  Dont know why I didn't think of editing the reporter myself, I was stuck on how to configure the `print()` function :)