# Element is not found while waiting. Need to know what that element is

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I am using protractor to test one of our non-angular apps. Due to the synchronization issues, I am waiting first for the element before doing an assertion. My wait code is like this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
elm = element(by.css(WebElements.locators.proDashboard.menuLogout));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 30000);
```

However, when the test did not see the element, it gives me this error:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

OR

```
Failed: Wait timed out after 10002ms
```

I am starting to have a problem with this as my test cases are growing and I am using page objects. There are long test cases where it is becoming very time consuming to check each element.

Is there any way I can see what the timed-out element is?

P.S.: I tried a logger using winston but it displays all the logs at once.

Comment: Waiting 30 secs for an element seems too be excessive. Have you set the ignoreSynchronization parameter to true for non-angular

Comment: Yes, I added it in my conf.js. My problem is that when it timed out, it just throws an time out error, but I don't know which element is that. Is there any way I can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you configure the `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` variable to only wait for `10002ms` per tests. You can change it on your conf file adding this:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
}
```

You can also specify timeout per `it` test with:

```
it("test that waits for 100000ms", function () {
    ...
}, 100000);
```

Comment: Would the specific wait value in "it" test override the defaultTimeoutInterval? Also, if an element timed out, how can I know what element is that? All I am seeing is that generic error and don't know what element caused that.

Comment: it was because there wasn't a specific "element" that timed out, but the test itself finished. And yes, the timeout in the `it` overrides `defaultTimeoutInterval`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did the defaultTimeoutInterval for 100000. While my wait on a specific element is 10000 only. As expected it threw an error of "Failed: Wait timed out after 10003ms" how can I make this to appear the specific element name? When running many test cases, it's hard to track which one is faulty. Any tips on this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792691/jasminenodeopts-printing-protractor-test-results